# About edition of a topic

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits, character-limit

Sometimes I Find some french in MSE, and I never can edit some "language mistakes" like in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250968/where-is-cauchys-wrong-proof)

When I have to justify my edit : [image]

I know numbers are 1 2 3 4 5 6... so why it doesn't work? :/

Thank you

Comment: It's the question/answer body that needs at least a six-character change. The edit summary has a different minimum character limit, which I believe is ten.

Comment: See [Minimum suggested edit length](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216/minimum-suggested-edit-length).

Comment: 1/ It appears that what you wanted to edit is a direct quote from a book. I don't think you should make stylistic edits in such a case... It doesn't matter that French evolved since 1821, you should just quote as it was written. 2/ You should read the sentence in its entirety. The sentence is "la somme $s$ de la série est aussi [...] fonction continue de $x$" (I omitted a part to make the structure clearer). Cauchy is saying that the sum $s$ is also a continuous function of $x$; writing "l'est aussi" would be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing "est aussi" by "l'est aussi" is a two-character edit: you added two characters. This is not allowed as a *suggested* edit.

You are welcome to make such edits after earning 2000 reputation points.

Comment: Thank you, I will need some years to reach them haha !